# how to draw a directed path on a map in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement highcharts maps with flight routes like this [Highchart-maps with flight routes](https://jsfiddle.net/knrsfeqx/1/), what i want to achieve is, the routes needs to be shown something like this [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEh4c.png).
is there anyway to achieve this using highchart maps?

any suggestions would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

```
function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
var arcPointX = (from.x + to.x) / (invertArc ? 2.4 : 1.9),
    arcPointY = (from.y + to.y) / (invertArc ? 2.4 : 1.9);
return 'M' + from.x + ',' + from.y + 'Q' + arcPointX + ' ' + arcPointY +
        ',' + to.x + ' ' + to.y;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your image and question are the same, but I assume you want to know how to draw a **directed path**. To achieve this I would use built-in SVG's [markers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker). You can create markers in Highcharts too:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function () {
        this.renderer
          .definition({
            tagName: 'marker',
            id: 'markerArrow',
            refY: 5,
            refX: 9,
            markerWidth: 11,
            markerHeight: 11,
            orient: 'auto',
            children: [{
              tagName: 'path',
              d: 'M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 Z',
              fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
              'stroke-width': 1,
              stroke: '#000000'
            }]
          });
      }
    }
  },
```

Then, in CSS, connect paths with markers:

```
.highcharts-series-3 .highcharts-point {
  marker-end: url(#markerArrow)
}
```

And demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xvhesL2n/

If you want to change the shape of a path, simply modify `pointsToPath` method. In my demo above you can observe straight lines instead of arcs:

```
function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
    return 'M' + from.x + ',' + from.y + 'L' + to.x + ',' + to.y;
}
```